# How to find public company information on employees joining, leaving, and their departments?

Tags: employees

I was wondering, if a potential employee or investor was interested in a publicly traded company how would that person find answers to the following questions?

1. How many employees have left the company (in a specified interval)
2. Why they left
3. What their job description was? Was it sales, marketing, engineering, finance, etc.?
4. How many people have joined the company (in a specified interval)
5. Which jobs did they take within the company?

Thanks

Comment: There may be laws regarding the release of certain information. For the rest of what you're looking for, there are competitive reasons to keep all that information private. Imagine if Google or Apple or Microsoft were seen bulking up the senior engineering talent in a particular department? Good sleuths can find that out, mostly on social media and combing press releases, but there is no general repository of employee movement records.

Comment: Most of this information is confidential.  Very few if any companies are going to freely release this sort of information.  The only way to get it in most cases would be a court order to release it during a discovery phase of a suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on this subject by any means, so I'll gladly yield to someone with more detailed knowledge.

But my understanding is: Publicly traded companies are required to disclose accounting-type information to the Securities and Exchange Commission and to shareholders. The kinds of things they have to report are your classic accounting categories: income, expenses, assets, liabilities, capital. They also have to report the names of certain top managers and how much they are paid. See, for example, http://www.inc.com/encyclopedia/sec-disclosure-laws-and-regulations.html Most of this should be in the annual report. If you are a stockholder, they should send you one automatically every year. If not, you can contact the company. Some companies post annual reports on their web sites. There are services that will supply annual reports, for example, http://www.nasdaq.com/services/annual-reports.aspx.

Most companies include total number of current employees in their annual report somewhere. I don't think that's required, but most do.

But to the best of my knowledge, none of the information you list in your question is required to be disclosed. "Why they left" would be almost impossible, as the company as no way to know for sure what was in someone's head when they turned in their resignation. It's common advice to tell people that when they quit a job, they should just say that they are leaving "for a better opportunity" or "for personal reasons", and not to say that it is because the boss is a jerk or company policies are stupid or otherwise complain about the company.

Comment: I think they're required to disclose when high-level employees leave,. but you're right that I don't think they give very specific employee count numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not voting to close, but any answer to your question with actual numbers attached will be specific to the company in question.

A more general answer is that is that these questions would only be answerable if the company was tracking the information, and for at least one of them, they can't and generally don't try.  For the rest, while they might HAVE the information, it may not be in an easily queryable format.

Finally, this is not the kind information that companies typically **desire** to be publicly available. Some will actively desire to supress the answers, others simple won't care to put any effort into it.

In short, you can take Joe's advice, and ask, but expect the answer to be "we don't provide that information".